# Is it possible to create a 2D jagged array of a generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Is it possible to create an two-dimensional array of a generic type parameter with only a size specified in Java?

To illustrate, can we create an array like this:

```
T[][] array = new T[x][];
```

Comment: Have you simply tried it? It works. The compiler is your friend.

Comment: @gexicide I tried for sure, but it does not work even for `T[] arr = new T[x];`. It gives `error: generic array creation`.

Comment: The problem is not the 2D jagged array. The problem is the type `T` which seems to be a generic type parameter. It is not possible to create arrays of generic type parameters.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to create an array of a generic type parameter. I'll edit the question since it's ambigious.

Answer (score 3):

You mention "generic" in your question and use the identifier T for your type, so I'm going to assume you are talking about creating an array of a generic type parameter.

You can't do that in Java. Arrays and generics don't mix very well. You can do it with reflection ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation)) but you might have an easier time doing this with a collection class instead. It would be a List of Lists, to get a 2D ragged container.

Answer (score 1):

Not with generics, but using a known class it is possible. For generic i would recommend using ArrayList or similar.

```
 String[][] array = new String[2][];
```

It can be used in this way:

```
array[0] = new String[1];
array[1] = new String[4];
array[0][0] = "Hello 0,0";
array[1][1] = "Hello 1,1 ";

System.out.println(array[0][0]);
System.out.println(array[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a generic multidimensional array. You cannot create one. However, you can create an `Object` array and then cast it. This is the "usual" way of creating generic arrays:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[][] array = (T[][])new Object[x][];
```

You need `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` because the cast is not safe and checked. From a typetheoretic point of view, it is even "wrong" (an array of type `Object` is NOT an array of `T`), but Java's type system has this inconsistency and this is the way to handle it.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that without success. 
When I created and returned the same array with casting in a method, and I try store this result from when I call the method, I got an error that I can't store an Object[][] in a (let's say) Integer[][].

Comment: @EmrehanTuzun: The behaviour you explain sounds strange. Please post your exact code that failed. (The method and the code that called it)

Comment: here is the code that fails: http://pastebin.com/y9TLjJMx. I'm trying to generalise this gist: https://gist.github.com/emrehan/bc24dea0878dcfe5cdcb